# what's the difference between ShowWindow and ShowWindowAsync?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am wondering what's the difference between those two Windows API method?

In which situation, we need to call ShowWindowAsync?

Comment: As implied by the name, `ShowWindowAsync` does not wait for the window to be shown before returning. `ShowWindow` waits for the window to be shown before returning. Depending on why you are showing the window, you may prefer one or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ShowWindow() sets the visibility state of a window created by the calling thread, ShowWindowAsync() is used when the calling thread did not create the window.

You would need to use [ShowWindowAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633549%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in a *multithreaded* application when changing the visibility state of a window from a different thread.

Comment: Can it used in multi-process environment?

Comment: Yes, you can use it in a multi-process enviroment.

Comment: This answer is somewhat misleading; you can call `ShowWindow` on windows created in other threads, or indeed other processes, quite happily.